# How do I place a Popup in my DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate correctly?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, popup

I have the following XAML ..

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Comparison key">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid DataContext="{Binding Columns}">
                <Popup x:Name="popKeyComparison" 
                                Placement="Bottom" 
                                IsOpen="True"
                                Width="200" Height="100">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Gray" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                        <Button>
                            <TextBlock>Somethingn here</TextBlock>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding KeyStatusText}" Name="txtKeyStatus">
                </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>                                
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

I am trying to show a Popup when editing the cell, this works fine but the problem is that the Popup does not close when clicking outside of the DataGrid. If for example I move the Window the Popup remains open but does not move with the Window.

Can anybody help with a solution to this?
Cheers.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution for this in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

Use a trigger which will set IsOpen property to False.

Comment: A trigger on what?

Answer (score 0):

Set [Popup.StaysOpen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.staysopen(v=vs.110).aspx) Property  to `False`.